# Modify the data so that each of the rides, instead of having a `park_name` property, has an appropriate park_id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So wrote this function where it should take an array of object and modify one of the object name to its identical property id. This is the function i wrote:

```
function prepareRidesData(rides, parks) {
  if (!rides.length) return [];

  const parksLookup = {};
  parks.forEach(({ park_id, park_name }) => {
    parksLookup[park_name] = park_id;
  });

  const updatedRides = rides.map((ride) => {
    ride.park_id = parksLookup[ride.park_name];

    delete ride.park_name;
    console.log(ride);
          
    return ride;
  })
  
  return updatedRides;
}
```

I do some testing using this format:

```
test("Return two park name with id only", () => {
  
        const input =([{
            ride_name: "Tidal Wave",
            year_opened: 2000,
            park_name: "Thorpe Park",
            votes: 1,
          },
          {
            ride_name: 'Nemesis',
    year_opened: 1994,
    park_name: 'Alton Towers',
    votes: 5,
          }]);
    
        const actual = prepareRidesData(input);
    
        expect(actual).toEqual([ {
            ride_name: "Tidal Wave",
            year_opened: 2000,
            park_id: 1,
            votes: 1,
          },
          {
            ride_name: "Nemesis",
            year_opened: 1994,
            park_id: 5,
            votes: 1,
          }]);
    
      });
```

The error i'm getting is - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Can someone help me identify where i am making the error for it not to be executing correctly.

It should change the park name to its identical park id

Comment: You don't pass `parks`. You pass an array of objects *(received by `prepareRidesData` as `rides`)* then do `parks.forEach`, but there are no parks.

Comment: If i remove the parks parameter. The object id is coming as undefined. I get his error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 3
    + Received  + 3

      Array [
        Object {
    -     "park_id": 1,
    +     "park_id": undefined,
          "ride_name": "Tidal Wave",
          "votes": 1,
          "year_opened": 2000,
        },
   
      ]

Comment: ... You don't **pass** a `parks` parameter: `const actual = prepareRidesData(input)`. There's no `parks` there, so it's undefined, so you get an exception when you try to call `forEach` on it.

Comment: Tried passing it inside prepareRidesData(parks) still coming as undefined

Comment: … The function takes two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition has two parameters, `rides` and `parks`:

```js
function prepareRidesData(rides, parks) {
```

But when you call it, you only pass one, `input`:

```js
const actual = prepareRidesData(input);
```

So `rides` gets the value of `input` and `parks` is left `undefined`, hence the error. You need to pass the parks into the function as well as the rides.

Comment: test.only("Return park name as id", ()=> {

   const rides = [];

        const parks =([{
            ride_name: "Tidal Wave",
            year_opened: 2000,
            park_name: "Thorpe Park",
            votes: 1,
          }]);
    
        const actual = prepareRidesData(parks, rides);
    
        expect(actual).toEqual([ {
            ride_name: "Tidal Wave",
            year_opened: 2000,
            park_id: 1,
            votes: 1,
          }]);
    
      });

Comment: console.log
    {
      ride_name: 'Tidal Wave',
      year_opened: 2000,
      votes: 1,
      park_id: undefined
    }

Comment: Your explanation of the function, the test content, and your comments, don’t match the function api nor what it does, and appears to show lack of understanding of the function as well as how to use it. So I don’t feel I can help sufficiently without explaining the function itself and how it works, which could take more than a comment’s worth and you said you wrote, so… I’m not sure I can adequately help you here? Or perhaps if you could update/clarify your explanation/understanding of the function and what you’re trying to do? I’m just at a loss of how exactly to help.